# Select multiple tables in related database in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net

Need help with to select 3 related databasetables in one query. The result is supposed to
be copied to my viewmodel. Byt i cant find how to write the query.

I have like this:

```
Dim l = db.myEntity.Where(Function(m) m.regnr.Contains(regnr) And m.ExtLok = True).Select(Function(m) m.Customer).tolist()
```

This query only select the one-to-on-related table "Customer", so my question is, how do i select more tables? Ive tried this

```
Dim l = db.myEntity.Where(Function(m) m.regnr.Contains(regnr) And m.ExtLok = True).Select(Function(m) m.Customer, m.Cars).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim item As myEntity = (from e in db.MyEntities.Include("MoreEntities").Include("OtherEntity") where m.field.contains("criteria") select e)
```

The key here is calling the `Include` method on the collection in the `In` clause.

Take a look at MSDN or Intelisense - `Include()` has several overloads.

Comment: I have tried your solution but with no go. Let say i have three tbales, table1, table2, table3. Table3 has a navigation key to both table1 and table2 in the model.
So i tried "Dim item as myEntity = (from e in db.table3.include("NavKey1").include("Navkey2") where field.contains(criteria) select e).Tolist()

This doesnt select anything, and no errors.

Comment: Did you make sure that your `Where` clause is correct?  Also, You declared  `item` as a singular `myEntity` but you are trying to assign a `List(Of myEntity)` to it.

Comment: Yes, i know the ´Where´ clause is correct, because the ´item´ contains the right number of values. The problem is the ´select´ or ´include´ that doesn seem to work. No data from the included tables is present in the ´list(of myEntity)´

Comment: My mistake....all the data was in the list. The problem was that i needed the navigationproperty also in my viewmodel, so i could present the data in my view. Thanx!